# FIndAll function for excel VBA (using cPearson) code

Tags: excel, findall, vba

Trying to find a range of cell values based on the find of a single value, then insert those values into a comment. My code is sound based on a single find value (thanks to a previous StackOverflow post) but I can't seem to get it to find multiple values as a range. (getting the "Not Found" message box even though the values are correct)

Here is the code that I get to run but does not find my referenced value...

This is based of cPearson's FindAll function and code, which I am having trouble understanding... Please let me know what additional information you need to assist and thank you for your time and consideration!

```
Function FindAll(SearchRange As Range, _
                FindWhat As Variant, _
                Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
                Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
                Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
                Optional BeginsWith As String = vbNullString, _
                Optional EndsWith As String = vbNullString, _
                Optional BeginEndCompare As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As Range

                End Function
Sub AddCommentAsDomainDescrReference2()
'Posted by Jeff Barrett 2015-04-10

    Dim sCommentText1 As String
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim cmmt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindString1 As Variant
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim FoundCell As Range

    str1 = "Domain Description: "

 'Loop Code, must specify range for i based on # of FieldDomainName

Sheets("Fields").Select
Range("K4").Select
For i = 4 To 59

    'Find DomainDescription in Domains based on Value from FieldDomainName
    FindString1 = ActiveCell.Value
    'Skip Empty Cells
    If FindString1 = "" Then GoTo Skip
    If Trim(FindString1) <> "" Then
    Set SearchRange = Sheets("Domains").Range("C:C")
            Set Rng1 = FindAll(SearchRange:=Sheets("Domains").Range("C:C"), _
                            FindWhat:=FindString1, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
    End If

            'Remove any existing comments, create comment and add text in FieldDomainName
            If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
                ActiveCell.ClearComments
                sCommentText1 = Rng1.Offset(0, 3).Value
                ActiveCell.AddComment.Text Text:=str1 & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & sCommentText1
                ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
                ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle

                'Format lines of text
                    With ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame
                            .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3

                    End With
                Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
Skip:
'End Loop
ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=0).Select
Next i

  'Resize Comment to fit text
  'posted by Dana DeLouis  2000-09-16
  Dim MyComments As Comment
  Dim lArea As Long
  For Each MyComments In ActiveSheet.Comments
    With MyComments
      .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
      If .Shape.Width > 300 Then
        lArea = .Shape.Width * .Shape.Height
        .Shape.Width = 300
        ' An adjustment factor of 1.1 seems to work ok.
        .Shape.Height = (lArea / 200) * 0.6
      End If
    End With
  Next ' comment

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to post the actual function code.

Comment: jbarker2160, I am going off the information found on http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/FindAll.aspx for the findall function posted on this site. I assume the function statement at the top of my code needs to be adjusted? I do not have an understanding of how to implement the function in vba code but I am experimenting on my own and trying to learn.  Any assistance or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't post anything here without all of the code that you used.  It doesn't matter where it came from.  I can't possibly know if you copied the function exactly or if you've made some typos etc.  You should not post links here.  Only code.  People will down vote your answers for that.

Comment: The above code is everything that I used. A subset of the above code is what I used previously to execute a single find, nothing more. I am trying to execute a FindAll function, which from what I have researched seems difficult and I may be missing code to be able to do that. I cited a reference from where I received the function that I am trying to implement as instructed in the "How to Ask" section of this website. If there is not enough info here for you to help, say so, but I can't supply you code I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a loop to solve my challenge instead of trying to make the FindAll function work. Below is the code:

```
Sub AddCmntWDomainsFINAL()
'Posted by Jeff Barrett 2015-04-10

    Dim FindString1 As String
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim FirstCell As String
    Dim sCommentText1 As String
    Dim cmmt As String
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim K As Long
    Dim L As Long
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook
    Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open("My Workbook1")
    Dim wbk2 As Workbook
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open("My Workbook2")

 'Loop Code, must specify range for i based on # of FieldDomainName

wbk2.Sheets("ETHN").Select
Range("L4").Select
For i = 4 To 15

    'Find DomainDescription in Domains based on Value from FieldDomainName
    FindString1 = ActiveCell.Value
    'Skip Empty Cells
    If FindString1 = "" Then GoTo Skip
    If Trim(FindString1) <> "" Then
            With wbk1.Sheets("HG Concepts v6.2").Range("R:R")
                    Set Rng1 = .Find(what:=FindString1, _
                                after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                    'Remove any existing comments, create comment and add text in FieldDomainName
                    'Posted by Darren Bartrup-Cook 2015-04-08
                    If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then FirstCell = Rng1.Address
                        Do While Not Rng1 Is Nothing
                            If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                                ActiveCell.ClearComments
                                    Msg = Environ("Domain Values: ") _
                                        & "Domain Values: " & vbLf & vbLf _
                                        & "Other"
                                ActiveCell.AddComment Msg
                                ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
                                ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
                                ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
                                ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.Width = 150
                                ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.Height = 250
                            Else
                                sCommentText1 = Rng1.Offset(0, 6).Value
                                ActiveCell.Comment.Text Text:=ActiveCell.Comment.Text & vbLf & sCommentText1
                                    With wbk1.Sheets("HG Concepts v6.2").Range("R:R")
                                        Set Rng1 = .FindNext(Rng1)
                                    End With
                                'Format lines of text
                                    With ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame
                                            .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                                            L = Len("Domain Values: ")
                                            K = InStr(1, Msg, "Domain Values: ")
                                              .Characters(K, L).Font.Bold = True
                                              .Characters(K + L, Len("Domain Values: ") - (K + L + 1)).Font.Bold = False
                                    End With
                                If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
                                    If Rng1.Address = FirstCell Then Exit Do
                                End If
                            End If
                        Loop
            End With
    End If
Skip:
'End Loop
ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=0).Select
Next i

End Sub
```